# Do we know what is the approximate size of this object on Pluto's surface?

Tags: identify-this-object, pluto, imaging

[Reportedly](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/parisantonio_mysterious-object-on-pluto-activity-6655477074574266368-Erkf) this object has been captured on Pluto's surface.

Which mission does this image originate from and can we estimate its size?

[image: snow_snail]

Comment: If we had the _original_ source, it would almost certainly include information on the scale of the image.

Comment: There is only one mission that ever took close-up images of Pluto.

Comment: @Polygnome from Earth at least

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This image comes a long strip which is [here (NASA page)](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/pluto-s-icy-plains-in-highest-resolution-views-from-new-horizons): it was taken by the [New Horizons spacecraft](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/newhorizons/main/index.html).

So the image is about 80km wide, and pixels are about 77-85 meters.  I guess the object is 5-10km long?

Comment: thank you @tfb! how did you find that?

Comment: @J.Doe I just looked through [NASA's images](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/newhorizons/images/index.html): it's pretty near the top of the page.

Comment: Should probably say in your answer that it's from the New Horizons spacecraft/mission since that was one of the OP's questions.

Comment: @astrosnapper: yes, it should: it does now!